# Redirect after login (previousUrl) not working on first login

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I am having an issue when wanting to redirect to `/my-account/change-organization` after the login is done. I have used this approach with storing the previousUrl, however, this does not work on the first login.

After the second login, it works as expected:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private routingService: RoutingService, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe((loggedIn) => {
        this.isUserLoggedIn = loggedIn;
      })
    );

    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.router.events
        .pipe(
          filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
          pairwise()
        )
        .subscribe((e: any) => {
          const previousUrl = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
          // get previousUrl
          if (previousUrl === '/login' && this.isUserLoggedIn) {
            this.routingService.go('/my-account/change-organization').catch((warn) => console.warn(warn));
          }
        })
    );
  }
```

I tried using breakpoints, but it simply does not access the router events subscriptions on the first login for some reason.

Any ideas or suggestions would help, thanks!

Comment: did you try without the filter? also which component does this (is the router in the component)?

Comment: this is in the app component

Comment: What is the value of 'isUserLoggedIn' on the first login attempt? Depending on how the rest of your app is setup you may have a race condition.

Comment: it does not even enter the router.events subscription on the first login